# How to implement a running balance column in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have googled this for two days now and can't find an answer I can use.
It's a simple "running balance" as seen in every other financial app. The things I have found either are getting sum totals (one total at the end), or react to PropertyChanged (my grid is not directly editable), or are half an answer ("use the CollectionView" but don't say how and I'm not seeing it).

How can I bind an ObservableCollection to a DataGrid and maintain a "running balance" as a calculated column (not as part of the model) that survives a sort on one of the columns?

(EDIT) Example of what I'm looking for

```
    Date    Payment    Deposit    Balance
09/01/2018     0.00    1500.00    1500.00
10/01/2018   100.00       0.00    1400.00
11/01/2018   234.00       0.00    1166.00
12/01/2018   345.00       0.00     821.00
```

... or, after a re-sort ...

```
    Date    Payment    Deposit    Balance
12/01/2018   345.00       0.00    -345.00
11/01/2018   234.00       0.00    -579.00
10/01/2018   100.00       0.00    -679.00
09/01/2018     0.00    1500.00     821.00
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `DataTable` to bind your `DataGrid`? `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyTable}">`

Comment: You need somewhere to put the total. Wrap each model in a viewmodel with a balance property. Copy this code https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2010/07/14/3/datagrid-per-row-running-totals bind a column to balance.

Comment: @Andy I already found that article. It doesn't survive a sort. When the order changes on the DataGrid it doesn't affect the order of the DataContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started by realizing this is presentation logic, so it belongs in the View. Realized what I should do is reorder the `ObservableCollection` and establish the running total at that time ([which led me here](https:////stackoverflow.com/questions/1834753/linq-to-sql-and-a-running-total-on-ordered-results)).

But I still couldn't get the `ObservableCollection` to refresh. If I replaced it with a new (sorted) `ObservableCollection` that broke the binding logic. So I went and [found this answer](https:////stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each) which eventually led me to [this GitHub](https:////gist.github.com/weitzhandler/65ac9113e31d12e697cb58cd92601091).

With the new class in place the xaml.cs turns into this:

```
private void DataGrid_OnSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    decimal runningTotal = 0.0M;
    //I have to maintain the sort order myself. If I let the control do it it will also resort the items again
    e.Column.SortDirection = e.Column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? ListSortDirection.Descending : ListSortDirection.Ascending;

    IEnumerable<RegisterEntry> tempList = RegisterList;

    switch (e.Column.Header.ToString())
    {
        case "Payment":
            tempList = e.Column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? tempList.OrderBy(item => item.Payment) : tempList.OrderByDescending(item => item.Payment);
            break;
        case "Transaction":
            tempList = e.Column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? tempList.OrderBy(item => item.TransactionDate) : tempList.OrderByDescending(item => item.TransactionDate);
            break;
        case "Payee":
            tempList = e.Column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? tempList.OrderBy(item => item.itemPayee) : tempList.OrderByDescending(item => item.itemPayee);
            break;
    }

    tempList = tempList
        .Select(item => new RegisterEntry()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            AccountId = item.AccountId,
            TransactionDate = item.TransactionDate,
            ClearanceDate = item.ClearanceDate,
            Flag = item.Flag,
            CheckNumber = item.CheckNumber,
            itemPayee = item.itemPayee,
            itemCategory = item.itemCategory,
            Memo = item.Memo,
            itemState = item.itemState,
            Payment = item.Payment,
            Deposit = item.Deposit,
            RunningBalance = (runningTotal += (item.Deposit - item.Payment))
        }).ToList();

    RegisterList.ReplaceRange(tempList);

    // Set the event as Handled so it doesn't resort the items.
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try a separate DataGrid right next to the first one.

Comment: This has the same issues with the added nightmare of keeping them scrolled to the same row at the same time. The visual presentation looks terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your dilemma. You want the running balance to show the effect of a particular transaction on the starting balance but that running balance must take into account the preceding transaction. I think [this article](https://classic.youneedabudget.com/support/article/running-balance) pretty well sums up (no pun intended) what you're looking to do right?

Binding a column to this calculation separate from the transaction model will be problematic. The DataGrid isn't designed to bind to multiple Data Sources. The idea is that a row in the grid represents a single data set. You might be able to get creative using the sort event and then reading the current value by row and calculating it that way but I don't think that is really the best way to go about it.

Instead, you could have the running balance as a property of the model but have it calculated when the transaction is loaded into the observable collection. This works for your scenario because you said that your users don't edit directly via the grid. So then you can transform the transaction before it is added to the ObservableCollection.

If you're loading the transactions from a database or deserializing from a file just mark that property as "unmapped" or use something like AutoMapper to map your transaction model to a transaction ViewModel.

Although I wrote this example using code behind it could just as easily be done in MVVM since were not directly referencing any ui components.

Maybe something like this would work?:

```xml
 <Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Running Balance" Binding="{Binding RunningBalance}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" >
            <Button x:Name="btnAddItem" Content="Add" Width="40" Height="30" Click="BtnAddItem_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        readonly Random _random;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _random = new Random();

            DataContext = this;

            Transactions = new ObservableCollection<Transaction>();
            // add some transactions to the collection to get things started
            AddTransaction(new Transaction()
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(5)),
                    Amount = -35.66M
                });

            AddTransaction(new Transaction()
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(4)),
                    Amount = -22.00M
                });

            AddTransaction(new Transaction()
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(3)),
                    Amount = -10.10M
                });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// All transactions are added to the collection through this method so that the running balance
        /// can be calculated based on the previous transaction
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="transaction"></param>
        void AddTransaction(Transaction transaction)
        {
            //find the preceding transaction
            var precedingTransaction = Transactions.Where(t => t.Date &lt; transaction.Date)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if(precedingTransaction == null)
            {
                //This is the earliest transaction so calc based on starting balance
                transaction.RunningBalance = StartingBalance + transaction.Amount;
            } else
            {
                //this is not the earliest transaction so calc based on previous
                transaction.RunningBalance = precedingTransaction.RunningBalance + transaction.Amount;
            }

            //Add the transactions to the collection with the calculated balance
            Transactions.Add(transaction);
        }

        void BtnAddItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddTransaction(new Transaction()
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now,
                    //generate a random dollar amount
                    Amount = (decimal)-Math.Round(_random.Next(1, 100) + _random.NextDouble(), 2)
                });
        }

        public decimal StartingBalance => 345.00M;

        public ObservableCollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Transaction
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public decimal RunningBalance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, no. This is the exact situation I'm trying to avoid. I can get a list of transactions, calculate a running balance and then never have it adjust. I WANT the "problem" mentioned in your article. If I sort the data differently the running balance should recalculate after a sort.

Comment: Your going to have to give more information or an example. Try a different name other than running balance because that apparently isn't what your after.